# Pandas Series of Conditional Probabilities

Tags: python, pandas, probability

My dataframe is as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'profile':np.random.choice(4, 20), 
    'kbps':np.random.choice(range(15), 20)
    })

    profile  kbps
0         1     8
1         1     1
2         0     8
3         1    11
4         0    11
5         1     3
6         1     7
7         1     5
8         0     5
9         1     3
10        2     3
11        1    13
12        3    10
13        0     6
14        0     3
15        2     4
16        3     7
17        0    11
18        0     4
19        0    10
```

I want to compute the following probabilities:

1. P(BW), where BW = kbps
2. P(BW | profile = i)
3. P(profile=i)
4. P(profile = i | BW) =  P(profile=i) *  P(BW | profile = i) / P(BW)

`1` can be computed as: 
`df['kbps'].map(lambda x : x/len(df))`

but I can directly compute `2` using: 
`df.groupby('kbps')['profile'].value_counts() / df.groupby('kbps')['profile'].count()`

```
kbps  profile
1     1          1.000000
3     1          0.500000
      0          0.250000
      2          0.250000
4     0          0.500000
      2          0.500000
5     0          0.500000
      1          0.500000
6     0          1.000000
7     1          0.500000
      3          0.500000
8     0          0.500000
      1          0.500000
10    0          0.500000
      3          0.500000
11    0          0.666667
      1          0.333333
13    1          1.000000
Name: profile, dtype: float64
```

`3` same as `1`

I's struggling to come up with `4`. Would it be the transpose of `2`?

My ultimate goal is to have a plot where the y-axis are the probabilities and the x-axis is the bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

I think the second equation is a little bit wrong. You should swap the position of kbps and profile.

Try this:

```
# 1. P(BW), where BW = kbps
equation1 = df.groupby('kbps')['profile'].count()/len(df)

# 2. P(BW | profile = i)
equation2 = (df.groupby('profile')['kbps'].value_counts() / df.groupby('profile')['kbps'].count())

# 3. P(profile=i)
equation3 = df.groupby('profile')['kbps'].count()/len(df)

# 4. P(profile = i | BW) = P(profile=i) * P(BW | profile = i) / P(BW)
equation4 = equation3*equation2/equation1
```

Output:

```
print(equation4.swaplevel().sort_index())

kbps  profile
0     0          0.500000
      2          0.500000
1     2          0.666667
      3          0.333333
3     0          1.000000
4     0          1.000000
5     2          0.333333
      3          0.666667
6     2          1.000000
7     0          1.000000
8     0          0.500000
      2          0.500000
10    2          1.000000
11    1          1.000000
13    1          0.500000
      3          0.500000
14    2          1.000000
dtype: float64
```